# Email address as select index in mysql for huge table query speed

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering about using emails for indexing. I realise that this is sub-optimal and that it's better to use an auto-incremented primary key. But in this case I'm trying to develop a lite application that does not require account registration to use.

```
SELECT account_id, account_balance, account_payments_received
FROM accounts
WHERE account_email = ?
LIMIT 1
```

This works ok at the moment with few users. But I'm concerned about when it reaches a million or more. Is there any way to index emails quickly?

I was thinking maybe I could use the first and second characters as keys? Maybe develop an index number for a=1, b=2, c=3 and so on.....

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: I think indexing using auto increment field or primary key will be more faster compare to these.

Comment: Yes, I know that is the optimal - but it just isn't possible for me to do that for my application - users will not bother to memorise their account_id, only their email

Comment: what is data type and length for account_email field

Comment: @ZafarMalik Currently it's set to char(255) but I'm open to changing that if there's a more efficient setting...

Comment: what is the problem if you sign email field as a unique or index it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You should keep a primary key with auto_increment, because it will provide you efficiency at the time of join with other tables.

2) Keep account_email field varchar(255) instead of char(255), so that can get free bytes back. Even varchar(100) will be enough.

3) create partially index on this field as per below command.

```
alter table accounts add index idx_account_email(account_email(50));
```

Note: varchar(50) will cover almost 99% emails.

Comment: Yes, I do have a primary key for my other internal queries - it's just queries directly from users when they check their balance for example.

Comment: I notice that my email is currently set to UNIQUE - you are suggesting I also set to INDEX is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I will change to varchar(100) that sounds like a good plan :)

Comment: if you want unique this field then no need index as unique is already have index. but for performance just reduce length for better index usage.

Comment: Can I find out someone else's balance by guessing their email?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a banking application and there's no way to siphon off money. I'm developing a site that allows people to earn beermoney basically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that any modern database will be able to perform this query (particuarily if it does NOT use LIKE) even on a table with a million rows in a fraction of a second.  Just make sure you have an index on the column.  i would add an autoincrement field also though as will always be simpler and quicker to use an integer to get a row.

Waht you are engaged in is [premature optimisation.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: What I'm engaged in is premature panic attack prevention :)

Comment: create a table with 1 Million randomly generated email addresses and see what sort of performance you get.  My guess is it will be better than you think.